# Android Starting 2 activity at a time causes issue

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have number of activities in my app. From front end I can start different different activities but I have back end as well, that means from server if i received a message than app has to take action on the message and start the activity based on the message.

My problem is that sometimes app received message from the server and app starts activity and at the same time user also performs click on UI and navigates to other activity. In this case one of my activity is not started as android can't start both activity at a time.

**Is there any INTENT LAG which can help to resolve this issue?**

**Right now what i am doing is if i received message from server than I am using one global flag and using that flag i am avoiding such situation,** but I am looking for better solution if anyone has any idea on this.

Comment: This seems a little intrusive, wouldn't it be possible to display a notification instead? The user can then touch that to open the notification without pressing the button at the same time.

Comment: No. I need to open the activity.

Comment: Still not really sure why you can't do it via a notification, what happens if the user isn't looking at your app at all and that message comes in?

Comment: @Pork That is exactly why OP needs to start the activity. If the user is looking at another app, he needs to have his app brought forward immediately to get the user's attention. It is an intrusive behaviour, but it sometimes can be the right thing to do (especially if this is an enterprise/business app).

Comment: @DavidWasser I understand what he's wanting to do, but unexpected behavior is also discouraged in enterprise environments. I mean, Scorpion's work around is just one example of the problems that can happen by trying to use an activity to get the users attention. There might be other cases that require more work arounds like what if the user wasn't actually looking at their phone at the time... I'm not drawing a line in the sand or anything, just that solving this problem might still leave the workflow open to other unforseen problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution sounds fine. There really isn't a good way to do this because Android discourages this behaviour. If your application requires this behaviour you will need to create a workaround, which it sounds like you have done.